# Quill - How to split a Delta into segments according to a word/character length?

Tags: quill

Let's say I have a Quill Delta that is 1,000 words or 6,000 characters.

I want to split this Quill Delta into 300-word or 1,800 character Deltas, while retaining all of its formatting.

In this case, I will end up with 4 Deltas.  The first 3 segments will have 300 words or 1800 characters, while the last segment will have the remainder amount, which will be 100 words or 600 characters.

In other words, I want to split a Delta with 1,000 words / 6,000 characters into...

1. Delta 1 - 300 words / 1800 characters
2. Delta 2 - 300 words / 1800 characters
3. Delta 3 - 300 words / 1800 characters
4. Delta 4 - 100 words / 600 characters

Is there an easy way to achieve this?  I'm scratching my head trying to figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the getContents() function in the quill API. It's documented [here](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#getcontents); you should just be able to change your length to grab a subsection of the delta data. In terms of how to get sections of it by word count, I'd imagine you'd have to do getText()(also on that page), tokenize to find words, figure out how many characters are there in each segment you want, then plug that into the getContents() function for length.